# SQL SELECT WHERE subquery (multiple rows) = subquery (multiple rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Forgive the length, this is quite hard to explain!

I've got two tables:

```
t_people
----------------------------------------
|  ID       |  surname   |  forenames  |
----------------------------------------
|  1        |  Baggins   |  Frodo      |
----------------------------------------
|  2        |  Took      |  Peregrin   |
----------------------------------------
|  3        |  Baggins   |  Bilbo      |
----------------------------------------

t_courseResults
--------------------------
|  personID |  result    |
--------------------------
|  1        |  98.0%     |
--------------------------
|  2        |  14.0%     |
--------------------------
|  3        |  56.0%     |
--------------------------
```

I then execute the following statement:

```
SELECT result FROM t_courseResults WHERE personID IN (SELECT ID FROM t_people WHERE surname like '%B')
```

...returning all course results for all people with a surname beginning with 'B' (2 rows).

Now let's say I've got a third table which stores a static list of people (e.g. a list of people in a particular department)

```
t_staticList
-------------
|  personID |
-------------
|  2        |
-------------
|  3        |
-------------
```

I would then want to execute something like this:

```
SELECT result FROM t_courseResults WHERE (SELECT personID FROM t_staticList) IN (SELECT ID FROM t_people WHERE surname like '%B')
```

Which is obviously garbage, but is something like this possible or am I being stupid? The idea would be that this would return just 1 row - Bilbo Baggins - as his name begins with 'B' and he is in the t_staticList table. Thanks!

Comment: Put your expected output in your question and it will make it easier to solve

Comment: And put full tables in there with all their fields

Comment: Just do inner join between the tables.

Comment: If you `JOIN` based on ids from the 3rd table it will only display those ids.
`FROM t_staticList stat JOIN t_courseResults course on  stat.id = course.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT result FROM t_courseResults WHERE PersonId IN (
  SELECT p.ID FROM t_staticList AS s
  INNER JOIN t_people as p ON p.ID = s.PersonId
  WHERE p.surname like '%B')
```

Answer (score 1):

USe `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT A.result
FROM t_courseResults AS A, t_staticList AS B
    INNER JOIN t_people AS C ON c.id = B.personID 
WHERE c.surname like '%B'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT result 
FROM t_courseResults 
WHERE personID IN 
   (SELECT p.ID FROM t_people p INNER JOIN t_staticList s ON p.PersonID = s.PersonID WHERE surname like '%B')
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from t_people A inner join t_courseResults B on A.ID=B.personID 
inner join t_staticList C on C.personID =B.personID  and A.surname  like ('B%')